# Allow multiple Clientst to connect to this server

Tags: java

So I have this server code: (Btw this is an IM program)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class Server extends JFrame{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7849253481287712961L;
    static String name =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter in your name.", "Name", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    boolean afk = false;
    double ver = 1.1;
   private JTextField userText;
   private ObjectOutputStream output;

   private ObjectInputStream input;
   private ServerSocket server;
   private Socket connection;
   private JTextPane images;
   private JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(); 

   public Server(){
      super(name+" - IM Server");
      images = new JTextPane();
      images.setContentType( "text/html" );
      userText = new JTextField();
      userText.setEditable(false);
      images.setContentType("text/html");
      if(name.isEmpty()){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name cannot be blank!", "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          System.exit(0);
      }
      userText.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
               sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
               userText.setText("");
            }
         }
      );
      add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      jsp.setViewportView(images);
      add(jsp);
      images.setEditable(false);
      setSize(700,400);
      setVisible(true);
      ImageIcon logo = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("CHAT.png"));
      setIconImage(logo.getImage());
   }


   public void startRunning(){
      try{
         server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
         String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
         if(OS.contains("windows")){
             showMessage("Open command prompt, and type ipconfig, find the right ip, and tell your friend that ip to connect!\n");
         }else if(OS.contains("mac")){
             showMessage("Open your network settings, find your ip, and tell your friend that ip to connect!\n");
         }else{
             showMessage("Looks like you're not running windows or mac. Find your ip address however you do, and tell your friend to connect using it!\n");
         }
         while(true){
            try{
               waitForConnection();
               setupStreams();
               whileChatting();
            }catch(EOFException eofException){
               showMessage("\n Server stopped! ");
            }finally{
               closestuff();
            }
         }
      }catch(IOException ioException){
         ioException.printStackTrace();
      }
   }


   private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
      showMessage("Running server on *.6789 \n");
      showMessage("Waiting for someone to connect... \n");
      connection = server.accept();
      images.setText("");
      showMessage(" Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
      showMessage("This is where images and text will show up.\nTo send an image, type\nimgURLHERE\nand replace URLHERE with the URL of the image.\nIt CANNOT have SPACES or EXTRA TEXT.\nalso, you can use\nHTML stuff :D");

   }


   private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
      output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
      output.flush();
      input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
      showMessage("\n Done! \n");
   }


   private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
      String message = " Connected! ";
      sendMessage(message);
      ableToType(true);
      do{
         try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
         }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
            showMessage("\n Cannot get other user's message.");
         }
      }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));
   }


   private void closestuff(){
      showMessage("\n Closing connections... \n");
      ableToType(false);
      try{
         output.close();
         input.close();
         connection.close();
      }catch(IOException ioException){
         ioException.printStackTrace();
      }
   }


   private void sendMessage(String message){
      try{
            name = "<html><font color=red>"+name;
             message = message.replace("*dissaproval*", "ಠ_ಠ");
             message = message.replace("*tbf*", "(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻");
             message = message.replace("*tableflip*", "(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻");
             if(message.contains("afk") & afk == false){
                 output.writeObject(name+" is now afk."+"</font></html>");
                 showMessage("\n"+name+" is now afk."+"</font></html>");
                 afk = true;
             }else if(message.contains("afk") & afk == true){
                 output.writeObject(name+" is no longer afk."+"</font></html>");
                 showMessage("\n"+name+" is no longer afk."+"</font></html>");
                 output.writeObject(name + " - " + message+"</font></html>");
                 afk = false;
             }else if(afk == true & !message.contains("afk")){
                 output.writeObject(name+" is no longer afk."+"</font></html>");
                 output.writeObject(name + " - " + message+"</font></html>");
                 showMessage("\n"+name+" is no longer afk."+"</font></html>");
                 showMessage("\n"+name+" - " + message+"</font></html>");
                 afk = false;
             }else if(message.contains("img")){
                 message = message.replaceAll("img", "");
                 message = "</font></html><html><img src='"+message+"'/>\n </html>";
                 showMessage("\n"+name+" - "+message+"</font></html>");
                 output.writeObject(name + " - " + message+"</font></html>");
             }else if(message.isEmpty()){
             }else{
                 output.writeObject(name + " - " + message+"</font></html>");
                 showMessage("\n"+name+" - " + message+"</font></html>");
             }
             output.flush();

          }catch(IOException ioException){
          }
       }


   private void showMessage(final String text){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
         new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               userText.requestFocus();
               HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)images.getDocument();
               HTMLEditorKit editorKit = (HTMLEditorKit)images.getEditorKit();
                try {
                    try {
                        editorKit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), text, 0, 0, null);
                        images.setCaretPosition(images.getDocument().getLength());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
         }
      );
   }


   private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
         new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               userText.setEditable(tof);
            }
         }
      );
   }

}
```

and this client code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
public class Client extends JFrame{
   /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1897693519598758260L;
static String name =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter in your name.", "Name", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
   boolean started = true;
   boolean afk = false;
   double ver = (1);
   private JTextField userText;
   private ObjectOutputStream output;
   private ObjectInputStream input;
   private String message = "";
   private String serverIP;
   private Socket connection;
   private JTextPane images;
   private JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(); 
   static String IP =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter in the IP (WITHOUT PORT) to connect to.", "IP", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
   public Client(String host){
      super(name+" - IM Client");
      serverIP = IP;
      if(serverIP.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty()){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name and/or IP can not be blank!!!", "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          System.exit(0);
      }
      userText = new JTextField();
      images = new JTextPane();
      userText.setEditable(false);
      userText.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
               sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
               userText.setText("");
            }
         }
      );
      add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      jsp.setViewportView(images);
      add(jsp);
      images.setEditable(false);
      images.setEditable(false);
      images.setContentType( "text/html" );
      HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)images.getDocument();
      images.setContentType("text/html");
      try {
        doc.insertString(0, "This is where images and text will show up.\nTo send an image, type\nimgURLHERE\nand replace URLHERE with the URL of the image.\nIt CANNOT have SPACES or EXTRA TEXT.\nalso, you can use\nHTML stuff :D", null );
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      setSize(700,400);
      setVisible(true);
      ImageIcon logo = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("CHAT.png"));
      setIconImage(logo.getImage());
   }
   public void startRunning(){
      try{
         connectToServer();
         setupStreams();
         whileChatting();
      }catch(EOFException eofException){
         showMessage("\n Client terminated connection.");
      }catch(IOException ioException){
         ioException.printStackTrace();
      }finally{
         closestuff();
      }
   }
   private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
      showMessage("Attempting to connect... \n");
      connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789);
      showMessage("Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName() );
   }
   private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
      output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
      output.flush();
      input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
      showMessage("\n Done! \n");
   }
   private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
      ableToType(true);
      do{
         try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
         }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotfoundException){
            showMessage("\n I dont know that object type.");
         }
      }while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));{
      }
   }
   private void closestuff(){
      showMessage("\n Shutting down...");
      ableToType(false);
      try{
         output.close();
         input.close();
         connection.close();
      }catch(IOException ioException){
         ioException.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
private void sendMessage(String message){
      try{
        name = "<html><font color=blue>"+name;
         message = message.replace("*dissaproval*", "ಠ_ಠ");
         message = message.replace("*tbf*", "(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻");
         message = message.replace("*tableflip*", "(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻");
         if(message.contains("afk") & afk == false){
             output.writeObject(name+" is now afk."+"</font></html>");
             showMessage("\n"+name+" is now afk."+"</font></html>");
             afk = true;
         }else if(message.contains("afk") & afk == true){
             output.writeObject(name+" is no longer afk."+"</font></html>");
             showMessage("\n"+name+" is no longer afk."+"</font></html>");
             output.writeObject(name + " - " + message+"</font></html>");
             afk = false;
         }else if(afk == true & !message.contains("afk")){
             output.writeObject(name+" is no longer afk."+"</font></html>");
             output.writeObject(name + " - " + message+"</font></html>");
             showMessage("\n"+name+" is no longer afk."+"</font></html>");
             showMessage("\n"+name+" - " + message+"</font></html>");
             afk = false;
         }else if(message.contains("img")){
             message = message.replaceAll("img", "");
             message = "</font></html><html><img src='"+message+"'/>\n </html>";
             showMessage("\n"+name+" - "+message+"</font></html>");
             output.writeObject(name + " - " + message+"</font></html>");
        }else if(message.isEmpty()){
         }else{
             output.writeObject(name + " - " + message+"</font></html>");
             showMessage("\n"+name+" - " + message+"</font></html>");

         output.flush();

      }}catch(IOException ioException){
      }
   }
   private void showMessage(final String m){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
         new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               userText.requestFocus();
               HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)images.getDocument();
               HTMLEditorKit editorKit = (HTMLEditorKit)images.getEditorKit();

            try {
                try {
                    editorKit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), m, 0, 0, null);
                    images.setCaretPosition(images.getDocument().getLength());
                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
         }
      );
   }
   private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
         new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               userText.setEditable(tof);
            }
         }
      );      
   }
}
```

and I want to know how to allow multiple clients to connect to the server. I am sorry if this is too complicated. Do I need a separate class for accepting clients, or do I somehow always check for clients and accept them? Also, how would I make it so the messages sent would appear on all the clients? Again, I'm sorry if this is too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

see the bottom of the page here [Supporting Multiple Clients](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html), in general:

```
while (true) {
    accept a connection;
    create a thread to deal with the client;
}
```